# URL regular expression help

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

Using this regular espression in my `urls.py` file, I get only the last letter in the add_or_remove param.
The url hits my view, but I am getting only `d` for add and `e` for remove. What am I doing wrong?

```
r'(?P<add_or_remove>[add|remove])/'
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django, but brackets [] signify a character set in regex. So [add] = a or d or d. Try using parentheses () instead of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Change the square brackets to round `()` brackets. The way it is now matches any of the characters `a` `d` `d` `|` `r` `e` etc...

Comment: By the way, you may find regexr.com helpful when debugging these kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `[...]` matches any *character* from set. Just remove bracers (using bracers from `(?P<>...)` is usually enough):

```
r'(?P<add_or_remove>add|remove)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I'm not familiar with Python. But if your trying to capture *add* or *remove*, your syntax is wrong. That is to say you don't want the brackets as this is notation for a character set - matching any in the set.

```
r'(?P<add_or_remove>add|remove)/'
```